# I want to do ternary operation like below code but code is not working fine

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

When I change `f7` value it will perform correctly till second condition but third and fourth condition does not trigger. What can I do please help me it stop on second condition?

```
var f7 = 5; 
var g7 = (f7 <= 3 ? 100 : (2 <= f7 < 4 ? 75 : (4 <= f7 < 5 ? 60 : (5 <= f7 < 6 ? 40 : 15))));
console.log(g7);
```

Comment: Ternary expressions are supposed to reduce simple conditions to one line, not to write code unreadable, and therefore impossible to maintain.

Comment: `2 <= f7 < 4` this is not doing what you expect. `2 <= f7 && f7 < 4`

Comment: There is no jQuery code here. Please make sure you don't add irrelevant information to the question.

Comment: " but third and fourth condition does not trigger" that's exactly how this should work. The result will always be either `100` *(for f7 <= 3)* or `75` *(any other value)*; the rest of the line is just noise. Every condition but the first is designed to resolve to `true`, no matter what. This line is basically `var g7 = f7 <= 3 ? 100: 75;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order in which you're executing the comparisons. I like to format ternary expressions over multiple lines to make them easier to work with, removing unnecesary brackets unless they help readability.

E.g.

```
var g7 = f7 <= 3 
  ? 100 
  : 2 <= f7 < 4 
     ? 75 
     : 4 <= f7 < 5 
        ? 60 
        : 5 <= f7 < 6 
           ? 40 
           : 15
```

That makes it a little clearer that your first comparison overlaps the values tested for in your second comparison. Do you really mean to check f7 <= 3 before checking that 2<=f7<4?

I would have thought this would be used with a strictly ascending range of values with no overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

thanks [@cid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8398549/cid) my calculations are done
`2 <= f7 && f7 < 4`
i use above code to do thanks

```
var g7 = f7 <= 3 ? 100 
: 2 <= f7 && f7 < 4 ? 75 
: 4 <= f7 && f7 < 5 ? 60 
: 5 <= f7 && f7 < 6 ? 40 
: 15;
```